# what is happening in following javascript function

Tags: javascript

[below i have given a javascript code picture `` can any one help me in this code. what do this code. help me in this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5Pd3.png)

```
function(){
    var _ = function()
        // The arguments object is an array-like object. It has a length property 
        // that corresponds to the number of arguments passed into the function
    { 
        var r={},a=arguments; 
        for(var i=0; i<a.length; i+=2)
            r[a[i]]=a[i+1];
        return r;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: I see the function have no name!

Comment: You are getting arguments as `(key1, value1, key2, value2 ...)`. And this object is creating a key-value pair

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of the script in use with some arguments.

```js
var _ = function() { 

  var r = {};
  var a = arguments; 

  for(var i=0; i<a.length; i+=2) {
     r[a[i]]=a[i+1]; 
  }
  console.log(r);
  return r; 
  
}

_('a','1','b','2');
```

Comment: **what is happening in following javascript function**. OP is looking for explanation, not  example

Comment: I figure one way to better understand what is happening was to watch an example.

Comment: That is one way but that it leaves lot of gaps in understanding. That is why we should try to explain what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The outer function does not make much sense but the inner function named '_' does this essentially _(1,2,3,4) function call will return {1:2,3:4}. Basically, odd arguments are keys and even arguments are values of the returned json object

Comment: Though explanation is correct, example `_(1,2,3,4)` is bad. Rather use meaningful values

Answer (score 0):

Function _ converts list of arguments into object

```
_(name1, value1, name2, value2, ...)
// returns { name1: value1, name2: value2, ... }
```